# Substitute reg_replace with reg_replace_callback in php

Tags: php, themes, preg-replace, opencart2.x, preg-replace-callback

I am rather new to OpenCart 2.1 and as part of an attempt to install new theme i have encountered what seems to be an issue migrating to PHP 5.5. The error that i am getting is:

> Unknown: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use
>   preg_replace_callback instead in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/projects/phpproject1/upload/admin/controller/module/tg_themegloballite_settings.php
>   on line 442. Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already
>   sent by (output started at
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/projects/phpproject1/upload/admin/index.php:80)
>   in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/projects/phpproject1/upload/system/library/response.php
>   on line 12

I believe the error is within file `tg_themegloballite_settings.php` on line 442 (somewhere within below block):

> ```
>           function mb_unserialize($serial_str) {
>               $out = preg_replace('!s:(\d+):"(.*?)";!se', 
>           "'s:'.strlen('$2').':\"$2\";'", $serial_str );
>               return unserialize($out);
>           }
> ```

I've been trying to fix it for a while now but cannot seem to get it to work, so any assistance will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a warning because the `e` modifier deprecation on `preg_replace` function (see http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php)

The equivalent replacement using `preg_replace_callback` is:

```
<?php

function mb_unserialize($serial_str) {
    $out = preg_replace_callback(
        '!s:(\d+):"(.*?)";!s',
        function ($matches) {
            return 's:' . strlen($matches[2]) . ':\"' . $matches[2] . '\";';
        },
        $serial_str);
    return unserialize($out);
}

echo "Function test: " . mb_unserialize('s:7:"my test"') . "\n";
```

References:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php